Cuando publico la app en azure services no me encuentra ningun endpoint
Tengo una app en .net8.0 donde estoy publicándola en mi app services de azure, pero al hacer una petición a cualquier endpoint me responde como que el recurso que estoy buscando no está disponible o que no tengo los permisos suficientes.
Por mucho que veo documentaciones, los pasos son simples.

Crear proyecto
Crear app services en azure
Configurar proyecto
Crear un perfil para publicar mi app en el app services que acabo de crear
Publican
Van a un endpoint donde se devuelve un json y les responde la API sin ningun problema.

A mi, en cambio, cuando publico la app, aparentemente sin ningún mensaje de error. Si voy a .net/api/Controller me indica que:
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

El swagger tampoco consigo que me funcione.
Aquí dejo mis clases que inician la APP por si fuera algún error de configuración.
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); // Aquí se especifica la clase Startup que configura la aplicación
            });
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // Este método se utiliza para configurar los servicios que utiliza la aplicación
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Nombre de tu API 32", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services.AddControllers(); // Agrega soporte para controladores de API
        services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
    }

    // Este método se utiliza para configurar la canalización de solicitudes HTTP
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); // Muestra páginas de error detalladas en entorno de desarrollo
        }

        // Habilitar Swagger
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Especificar la ruta base para la documentación de Swagger
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Nombre de tu API v11");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            // La ruta debe coincidir con la configuración anterior
        });

        app.UseRouting(); // Habilita el enrutamiento de solicitudes HTTP

        app.UseAuthorization(); // Habilita la autorización (si se utiliza)

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers(); // Configura los controladores de API
        });
    }
}


la ruta a tu api es .net/api/controller???? Usualmente swagger se apaga en produccion a proposito.. es logico que no tengas swagger...

si, la ruta deberia ser correcta. Aunque se apagara en produccion me gustaria hacer peticiones a mis endpoints

que quiere decir que debe ser asi? en localhost tu ruta es asi? Y swagger se apaga por defecto, no se como prenderlo en prod..

Si, en mi localhost me funciona perfectamente, es a la hora de hacer el deploy a azure

pero esa es tu ruta en localhost??? es localhost/.net/api/controller??? dudo que esa sea tu ruta...

haber, el problema esta en o la forma en como se publica la APP en azure o tema de alguna configuracion en azure. Si vas a decir una cosa tan tonta como que el problema esta en la URL que no es la correcta, cuando te estoy diciendo que no, mejor deja de hacerme perder el tiempo en estas respuestas.

ok suerte con eso entonces...
